# crop and resize images to train a support vector machine

Tags: python, opencv, svm

I use OpenCV(Python) to detect objects of the same class using HOG+SVM. I'm following an example of the Udacitiy-Project to detect vehicle: visit https://github.com/TusharChugh/Vehicle-Detection-HOG/blob/master/src/vehicle-detection.ipynb . In this Example they use a prepared data set of vehicle, which contains cropped and resized images.

I'm asking if someone had an idea to crop and resize images, which contains objects and background in the same image? or how to label images and integrate them in the example mentioned above?
I use Windows 10 and Python 3.6.

thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to create a program in which you can select regions to be cropped from images using mouse events. [SEE THIS](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_mouse_handling/py_mouse_handling.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Read a negative input and convert to a Histogram of oriented gradients (HOG) 
    samples = []
    labels = []   
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(negative_path, '*.jpg')):
        img = cv2.imread(filename, 1) 
        hist = hog(img)
        samples.append(hist)
        labels.append(1)

For the positive samples use the same code as above but with:
    labels.append(0)

then just train the svm modell with:
    svm.train(samples, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, labels)
```